cant log into Connect an account under Microosft
I was connected before the upgrade to the new LTSR 24.04.1 I signed myself out troubleshooting an issue and now can't get back in. I click on the button in settings and it takes me to the sign-in page but keeps insisting my account does not exist but when I go to the forgot password side it does see I have an account.

Question is not clear. Add some details please. Sign out of what? What exactly are you trying to do?

sorry I am talking about h the Settings >Online Accounts> under Connect an Account \ Microsoft not the Microsoft 365 the one that is just listed as Microsoft.
